# Getting NoClassDefFoundError using Spark with spark-cassandra-connector 3.1.0

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I've been trying to submit a spark application but get the following exception:

```
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/Users/alisaberi/Desktop/test-great-expectations/spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.2.0.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
21/11/13 13:17:42 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2021-11-13T13:17:46+0330 - INFO - Great Expectations logging enabled at 20 level by JupyterUX module.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.2.0
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.driver.
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: examstat
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO ResourceProfile: Default ResourceProfile created, executor resources: Map(cores -> name: cores, amount: 1, script: , vendor: , memory -> name: memory, amount: 1024, script: , vendor: , offHeap -> name: offHeap, amount: 0, script: , vendor: ), task resources: Map(cpus -> name: cpus, amount: 1.0)
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO ResourceProfile: Limiting resource is cpu
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO ResourceProfileManager: Added ResourceProfile id: 0
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: alisaberi
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: alisaberi
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(alisaberi); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(alisaberi); groups with modify permissions: Set()
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 62135.
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMasterHeartbeat
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /private/var/folders/4q/qc3xhr1x6qx5jr9604nl91w40000gn/T/blockmgr-e6d2444c-2aa6-4690-ac82-7a4ab1d86b6b
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 434.4 MiB
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://192.168.1.3:4040
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:///Users/alisaberi/Desktop/test-great-expectations/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12-3.1.0.jar at spark://192.168.1.3:62135/jars/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12-3.1.0.jar with timestamp 1636796867038
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host 192.168.1.3
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO Executor: Fetching spark://192.168.1.3:62135/jars/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12-3.1.0.jar with timestamp 1636796867038
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /192.168.1.3:62135 after 42 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
21/11/13 13:17:47 INFO Utils: Fetching spark://192.168.1.3:62135/jars/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12-3.1.0.jar to /private/var/folders/4q/qc3xhr1x6qx5jr9604nl91w40000gn/T/spark-3961cb18-dacf-4940-a5ff-36d1bbc2c3bb/userFiles-89f4f184-ba26-4a28-b83f-52cec85d7563/fetchFileTemp11862606911562884947.tmp
21/11/13 13:17:48 INFO Executor: Adding file:/private/var/folders/4q/qc3xhr1x6qx5jr9604nl91w40000gn/T/spark-3961cb18-dacf-4940-a5ff-36d1bbc2c3bb/userFiles-89f4f184-ba26-4a28-b83f-52cec85d7563/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12-3.1.0.jar to class loader
21/11/13 13:17:48 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 62138.
21/11/13 13:17:48 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 192.168.1.3:62138
21/11/13 13:17:48 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
21/11/13 13:17:48 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.3, 62138, None)
21/11/13 13:17:48 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.1.3:62138 with 434.4 MiB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.3, 62138, None)
21/11/13 13:17:48 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.3, 62138, None)
21/11/13 13:17:48 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.1.3, 62138, None)
21/11/13 13:17:48 WARN SparkSession: Cannot use com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions to configure session extensions.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/spark/connector/util/Logging
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:825)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:723)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:646)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:604)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:576)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:468)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.$anonfun$applyExtensions$1(SparkSession.scala:1194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.$anonfun$applyExtensions$1$adapted(SparkSession.scala:1192)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$applyExtensions(SparkSession.scala:1192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.<init>(SparkSession.scala:104)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.util.Logging
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 33 more
21/11/13 13:17:48 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir.
21/11/13 13:17:48 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/Users/alisaberi/Desktop/test-great-expectations/spark-warehouse'.
/Users/alisaberi/Desktop/test-great-expectations/spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/context.py:77: FutureWarning: Deprecated in 3.0.0. Use SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate() instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alisaberi/Desktop/test-great-expectations/test.py", line 33, in <module>
    sqlContext.read\
  File "/Users/alisaberi/Desktop/test-great-expectations/spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 164, in load
  File "/Users/alisaberi/Desktop/test-great-expectations/spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.2-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1309, in __call__
  File "/Users/alisaberi/Desktop/test-great-expectations/spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
  File "/Users/alisaberi/Desktop/test-great-expectations/spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.2-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o56.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/spark/connector/util/Logging
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:825)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:723)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:646)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:604)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.DefaultSource.getTable(DefaultSource.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.DefaultSource.inferSchema(DefaultSource.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2Utils$.getTableFromProvider(DataSourceV2Utils.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$1(DataFrameReader.scala:233)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.util.Logging
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 28 more

21/11/13 13:17:49 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
21/11/13 13:17:49 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.1.3:4040
21/11/13 13:17:49 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
21/11/13 13:17:49 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
21/11/13 13:17:49 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
21/11/13 13:17:49 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
21/11/13 13:17:49 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
21/11/13 13:17:49 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
21/11/13 13:17:49 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
21/11/13 13:17:49 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/4q/qc3xhr1x6qx5jr9604nl91w40000gn/T/spark-ef03b69b-8170-49e1-a24f-af46ff8ada7d
21/11/13 13:17:49 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/4q/qc3xhr1x6qx5jr9604nl91w40000gn/T/spark-3961cb18-dacf-4940-a5ff-36d1bbc2c3bb/pyspark-42c7c117-c948-4b16-82a6-39017769cff9
21/11/13 13:17:49 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/4q/qc3xhr1x6qx5jr9604nl91w40000gn/T/spark-3961cb18-dacf-4940-a5ff-36d1bbc2c3bb
```

The application use `spark-cassandra-connector` to read from cassandra. Here is the code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

spark = SparkSession\
         .builder\
         .appName("Test")\
         .master('local[*]') \
         .config('spark.cassandra.connection.host', 'localhost') \
         .getOrCreate()

spark.read\
     .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
     .options(table="gps", keyspace="test")\
     .load().show()
```

I've tried two different approaches to submit the application:

`$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.1.0 ./test.py`

`$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --jars /Full/Path/to/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12-3.1.0.jar`

Also when I run the same code in `pyspark` shell, it works fine.

`Spark 3.2.0`
`spark-cassandra-connector 3.1.0`
`cassandra 4.0.1`

Comment: what version of Java used? add output of `java -version`. I can't reproduce it - works just fine with java 8, 11, 15. with both approaches

Comment: @AlexOtt Here is the output of `java --version`: 
```java 15.0.2 2021-01-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.2+7-27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: try to use java 11. Officially Spark is compatible only with 8 and 11. From documentation: *Spark runs on Java 8/11, Scala 2.12*

Comment: @AlexOtt tried java 8 but still no success

Comment: strange. works for me out of box with your code